# Android importing project of different API level

Tags: android, api

I am already having one small project in android that is build in API-10.

And i am using the latest version of the API-17 and having the same SDK manager.

Now when i import this project it shows error like **Unable to resolve target 'android-10'** and some more lines.

So, when i Googled about this problem i found that i think i need to download API-10 and the SDK.

So i wanted to know why its needed?

Because my existing code is built in API-10 then i think it should be compatible with API-17.

I am new to Android i just understood some concepts like Activity, Services and many more but when i came around this issue i really shocked?

I just wanted to understand why its needed while i am already having SDK for API-17?

Comment: what does the manifest file say about <uses-sdk ... /> ?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by adding targetSdkVersion to the manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and clean your project, that might also help

Comment: when i done this change now its working but now its unable to find the layout how can i resolve it? R.java is missing from gen folder.

Comment: if R.Java is missing, you just need to clean your project. It means that the files that are automatically generated are not made yet

Comment: When i cleaned project then the file was not generated?what can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What that means is you need to start your `Android SDK Manager` and download and install `API Level 10`. Why do you need API Level 10 ? Well, the project you are importing needs that API level.